# Soap Mismatch between Java model and WSDL model found

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm developing an `SOAP Service` in Java but i encountered this error:

```
WARNING: Mismatch between Java model and WSDL model found, For wsdl operation 
{http://database.unitn.it/}isLoginOkay,There is no matching wsdl fault with detail 
QName {http://interfaces.database.unitn.it/}Exception
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: Unknown JAXBContext 
implementation: class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
at  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.getJAXBFactory(BindingContextFactory.j
ava:192)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:134)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:152)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:241)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:224)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.PayloadQNameBasedOperationFinder.getWSDLOperationMapping(PayloadQNameBasedOperationFinder.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.OperationDispatcher.getWSDLOperationMapping(OperationDispatcher.java:82)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Packet.getWSDLOperationMapping(Packet.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Message.getOperation(Message.java:284)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Message.getOperation(Message.java:302)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Message.isOneWay(Message.java:379)

...
```

I am working with java 1.8 and everything run on localhost. The wsdl seams to work fine.
I do not know what the problem could be. I tried a lot to solve the problem but I have not four no one thread that talk about this problem.
Please help.

EDIT:

Here the publisher:

```
private static final String mUrl = "http://localhost:" + Ports.MASTER_DATABASE_SERVICE + "/database";

public static void launch() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("----Starting on ..." + mUrl);
    Endpoint.publish(mUrl, new Database());
    System.out.println("----SOAP Service started!!!!");
}
```

Here the interface for the client part:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface DatabaseAPIsInterface
{

    @WebMethod
    public User isLoginOkay(String password, String email) throws Exception;

}
```

Here the implementation of the method `isLoginOkay(...)`

```
@Override
public User isLoginOkay(String password, String email) throws Exception
{
    Database db = null;
    try
    {
        db = fromConnectionPool();
        Dao<User, Integer> dao = createPersonDAO(db);
        throwIfSomeNull(password, email);

        QueryBuilder<User, Integer> builder = dao.queryBuilder();

        User user = builder.where().eq(User.FIELD_NAME_EMAIL, email).and().eq(User.FIELD_NAME_PASSWORD, password).queryForFirst();
        if (user != null) return user;
        else throw new FileNotFoundException("User does not exist");

    } finally
    {
        close(db);
    }
}
```

And here the client part:

```
    String mUrl = "http://localhost:" + Ports.MASTER_DATABASE_SERVICE + "/database?wsdl";
    URL url = new URL(mUrl);
    QName qname = new QName("http://database.unitn.it/", "DatabaseService");
    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
    DatabaseInterface database = service.getPort(new QName("http://database.unitn.it/", "DatabasePort"), DatabaseAPIsInterface.class);
    User user = database.isLoginOkay(password, email);
    System.out.println(user);
```

Comment: Does the `throws` clause of `myMethod` exactly match the faults specified in the corresponding <operation> in the .wsdl document?  (Also, you may want to stick with Java 1.7 until 1.8 is both out of beta and has had at least one minor release update after its initial public release, unless you really need the 1.8 language features.)

Comment: could you paste your publisher class from implementation and service part of wsdl here.

Comment: I want use java 1.8 if it is possible. And one more thing, I am using IntelliJIEA

Comment: Check my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721384/web-services-mismatch-between-java-model-and-wsdl-model-found-for-wsdl-operat/43737344#43737344