# web-services - Mismatch between Java model and WSDL model found, For wsdl operation

Tags: web-services

```java
@WebServiceClient(name = "SalesCustomerSelectService", wsdlLocation = "abc.wsdl", targetNamespace = "url path + api=SalesCustomerSelect") 
public class SalesCustomerSelectService extends Service {
public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;
public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("sx url + &api=SalesCustomerSelect", "SalesCustomerSelectService");
public final static QName SalesCustomerSelect = new QName("sx url + &api=SalesCustomerSelect", "SalesCustomerSelect");
static {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("url path + SalesCustomerSelect.wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SalesCustomerSelectService.class.getName())
            .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                 "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "url pathSalesCustomerSelect.wsdl");
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
@WebEndpoint(name = "SalesCustomerSelect")
public SalesCustomerSelect getSalesCustomerSelect() {
    return super.getPort(SalesCustomerSelect, SalesCustomerSelect.class);
    }
}

@WebService(targetNamespace = "url path + api=SalesCustomerSelect", name = "SalesCustomerSelect")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface SalesCustomerSelect {

@WebMethod(operationName = "SalesCustomerSelect", action = "url path + api=SalesCustomerSelect")
@Action(input = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", output = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", fault = {})
@WebResult(name = "SalesCustomerSelectResponseContainerList", targetNamespace = "url path + api=SalesCustomerSelect", partName = "parameters")
public SalesCustomerSelectResponseContainerList salesCustomerSelect(
    @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "SalesCustomerSelectRequestContainer", targetNamespace = "url path + api=SalesCustomerSelect")
    SalesCustomerSelectRequestContainer parameters) throws FaultMsg;
}
```

In my main class I am changing the endpoint url as suggested in this portal as

`this.erpUrl` is actually an url path

```java
final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName(this.erpUrl+"api=SalesCustomerSelect", "SalesCustomerSelectService");
final QName SERVICE_NAME1 = new QName(this.erpUrl+"api=SalesCustomerSelect", "SalesCustomerSelect");

try{
    wsdlURL = new URL(this.erpWsdl + "api=SalesCustomerSelect");
}
catch(Exception e){}

SalesCustomerSelectService customerService = new SalesCustomerSelectService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
SalesCustomerSelect customerPort = customerService.getPort(SERVICE_NAME1, SalesCustomerSelect.class);
```

I am getting the error

```
2017-05-01 17:44:27.248  WARN 8904 --- [io-8080-exec-20] c.s.x.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl   : Input Action on WSDL operation SalesCustomerSelect and @Action on its associated Web Method salesCustomerSelect did not match and will cause problems in dispatching the requests
2017-05-01 17:44:27.248  WARN 8904 --- [io-8080-exec-20] c.s.x.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl   : Mismatch between Java model and WSDL model found, For wsdl operation {https://gwws.greywolf.com/sxtest/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect}SalesCustomerSelect,There is no matching wsdl fault with detail QName {https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect}FaultContainer
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code for the Java model and the WSDL for us to decipher.
I feel some detail is missing that would assist to decipher the problem.
I would expect something like this as the full statement of the problem.

```
Mismatch between Java model and WSDL model found, For wsdl operation {http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/interface}sendSms,There is no matching wsdl fault with detail QName {http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v2_1}PolicyException_type
```

In my example above the error would due to a mistmatch in the names of the Java model whose name is, `@XmlType(name = "PolicyException_type"`
and the operation name in the WSDL.

Counter checking the `ObjectFactory` class , it clearly has a mismatch since the Java model refers to PolicyException_type as the name where as the operation name in Object factory to the operation name is: `PolicyException` as seen below.

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v2_1", name = "PolicyException")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: as suggested i am posting all the related files one by one.

Comment: requirement is to generate cxf client classes and during run time while using the client classes we should be able to set any one the below wsdl end points dynamically.

Comment: dev server wsdl is https://gwws.greywolf.com/sxtest/wsdl.aspx?result=wsdl&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect

Comment: prod server wsdl is dev server wsdl is https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/wsdl.aspx?result=wsdl&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect

Comment: wsdl2 java syntax used is

Comment: WSDLToJava.main(new String[] {  "-p","net.secondphase.sxe.infor."+apiName,"-b","src/main/resources/jaxb-custom.xml",  "-d", "src/main/java", "-client","-wsdlLocation","https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/wsdl.aspx?result=wsdl&v=1&api="+apiName, "E:\\SecondPhase-app\\SxeGen/wsdl/"+apiName+".wsdl" });

Comment: entry in jaxb-customer.xml is

Comment: <jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

Comment: @WebService(targetNamespace = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", name = "SalesCustomerSelect")
    @XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)

Comment: public interface SalesCustomerSelect {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "SalesCustomerSelect", action = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect")
    @Action(input = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", output = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", fault = {})
    @WebResult(name = "SalesCustomerSelectResponseContainerList", targetNamespace = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", partName = "parameters")

Comment: public SalesCustomerSelectResponseContainerList salesCustomerSelect(
        @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "SalesCustomerSelectRequestContainer", targetNamespace = "https://gwws.greywolf.com/sx/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect")
        SalesCustomerSelectRequestContainer parameters
    ) throws FaultMsg;
    }

Comment: In my main class using the above cxf class files as below

Comment: final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("https://gwws.greywolf.com/sxtest/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", "SalesCustomerSelectService");
        final QName SERVICE_NAME1 = new QName("https://gwws.greywolf.com/sxtest/ws.aspx?result=ws&v=1&api=SalesCustomerSelect", "SalesCustomerSelect");
        try{
            wsdlURL = new URL(this.erpWsdl + "api=SalesCustomerSelect");
        }catch(Exception e){}

Comment: SalesCustomerSelectService customerService = new SalesCustomerSelectService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        SalesCustomerSelect customerPort = customerService.getPort(SERVICE_NAME1, SalesCustomerSelect.class);
        ((BindingProvider)customerPort).getRequestContext().put("set-jaxb-validation-event-handler", Boolean.FALSE);

Comment: @venkat,
Woow, there is a place to tag code in stackoverflow, kindly wrap the code in {} tags.